# How is the compile-time magic of the Play framework's SQL operator working?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am very impressed with the compile-time safety of Scala code like this:

```
val searchCountryPrefix:String = ....

val sql = SQL"""
  select
    cn.name, cn.indepyear, c.name
  from
    city c
    join country cn on c.id = cn.capital
  where
    cn.name like $searchCountryPrefix
  """
```

...because if I make a typo in the string, and e.g. use something wrong:

```
  ...
  where
    cn.name like $searchCountyPrefix -- instead of country, it says county
  """
```

...then the Scala compiler catches it and reports it.

I've never seen such compile-time magic in any other language except Lisp - how is the Play framework doing this?

And more importantly, can I do such magic compile-time string checking in my own libraries?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to Play, it is a feature of Scala. You can learn more about String interpolation here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was hoping! Can you please point to the relevant code? I would like to see how the SQL interpolator works, so that I can build interpolators of my own.

Comment: @ttsiodras you can find the Anorm code here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.6/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/package.scala#L48 Otherwise the SIP already describes pretty well how to write your own interpolation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I can already think of many uses for this Scala feature.